# Python - How to retrieve data with Django Restframework from firebase database (not the SQL db) and send to a client?

Tags: python, django, firebase, flutter, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest API and I can perfectly fetch data from a my database to a flutter client app. But I would like to fetch data from firebase database to the client via the API.
In other words I would like to send data in firebase database via my Django restframework API to the Flutter app. And I don't want to send data from my actual db SQL lite.
I'm new to python and django
This is what I tried so far..

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from myapi import models
from .serializers import ApiSerializer

class ListTodo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Myapi.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer

class DetailTodo(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = models.Myapi.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapi import models

class ApiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'topic',
            'guides'
        )

        model = models.Myapi
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

    class Myapi(models.Model):
        topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        guides = models.TextField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.topic
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListTodo, DetailTodo

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListTodo.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailTodo.as_view())
]
```

This code here retrieve a list of users that I would like to send throu API to the Flutter client app

```
users = db.child("users").get()
print(users.val())
```

Thank you